# How Do I Draw 3D Primitives in WP

Tags: visual-studio-2012, 3d, xna, windows-phone

I'm a green horn with XNA and I've been trying to get past this issue for several days but every time I try to get it done I get an exception or the application just plain exits and it has been very irritating.

I want to be able to draw a 3D primitive without having to have a model premade for it. I had this code first:

```
VertexPositionColor[] primitiveList = { new VertexPositionColor(
                    new Vector3(1,1,0), Color.White), new VertexPositionColor(
                    new Vector3(0,1,-1), Color.White) };

short[] lineListIndices = { 0, 1 };

Controller.CurrentGame.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
    PrimitiveType.LineList,
    primitiveList,
    0,  // vertex buffer offset to add to each element of the index buffer
    2,  // number of vertices in pointList
    lineListIndices,  // the index buffer
    0,  // first index element to read
    1   // number of primitives to draw
);
```

And I get an InvalidOperationException with the following

> Message    "Both a vertex shader and pixel shader must be set on the device before any draw operations may be performed."

So then I try following the instructions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203926.aspx and end up with the following code:

```
BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(Controller.Graphics.GraphicsDevice);

basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
basicEffect.View = Controller.Cam.view;
basicEffect.Projection = Controller.Cam.projection;

// primitive color
basicEffect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
basicEffect.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
basicEffect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);
basicEffect.SpecularPower = 5.0f;
basicEffect.Alpha = 1.0f;

basicEffect.LightingEnabled = true;
if (basicEffect.LightingEnabled)
{
    basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled = true; // enable each light individually
    if (basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled)
    {
        // x direction
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(1, 0, 0); // range is 0 to 1
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
        // points from the light to the origin of the scene
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.SpecularColor = Vector3.One;
    }

    basicEffect.DirectionalLight1.Enabled = true;
    if (basicEffect.DirectionalLight1.Enabled)
    {
        // y direction
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight1.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0, 0.75f, 0);
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight1.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, -1, 0));
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight1.SpecularColor = Vector3.One;
    }

    basicEffect.DirectionalLight2.Enabled = true;
    if (basicEffect.DirectionalLight2.Enabled)
    {
        // z direction
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight2.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f);
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight2.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
        basicEffect.DirectionalLight2.SpecularColor = Vector3.One;
    }
}

VertexDeclaration vertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),
        new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
    }
);

Vector3 topLeftFront = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
Vector3 bottomLeftFront = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Vector3 topRightFront = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
Vector3 bottomRightFront = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Vector3 topLeftBack = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3 topRightBack = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3 bottomLeftBack = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3 bottomRightBack = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

Vector2 textureTopLeft = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector2 textureTopRight = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);
Vector2 textureBottomLeft = new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f);
Vector2 textureBottomRight = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);

Vector3 frontNormal = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Vector3 backNormal = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3 topNormal = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 bottomNormal = new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 leftNormal = new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 rightNormal = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

VertexPositionNormalTexture[] cubeVertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[6];

// Front face.
cubeVertices[0] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    topLeftFront, frontNormal, textureTopLeft);
cubeVertices[1] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    bottomLeftFront, frontNormal, textureBottomLeft);
cubeVertices[2] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    topRightFront, frontNormal, textureTopRight);
cubeVertices[3] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    bottomLeftFront, frontNormal, textureBottomLeft);
cubeVertices[4] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    bottomRightFront, frontNormal, textureBottomRight);
cubeVertices[5] =
    new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
    topRightFront, frontNormal, textureTopRight);

RasterizerState rasterizerState1 = new RasterizerState();
rasterizerState1.CullMode = CullMode.None;
Controller.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState1;
foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();

    Controller.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
        0,
        12
    );
}
```

And I get the following Exception

> Message    "A valid vertex buffer (and a valid index buffer if you are using indexed primitives) must be set on the device before any draw operations may be performed."

I know I shouldn't have all of this code in the same place, but I just want to be able to get something to draw so I can see how it works but nothing works and I can't seem to load any examples into VS.

As I've said I'm rather new and beyond the question I would also greatly appreciate any kind of reading material that would point in the right direction for 3D XNA. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Documentation sometimes helps. Unfortunately `DrawPrimitives` isn't so useful, but [`DrawIndexedPrimitives` has some example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawindexedprimitives.aspx) that shows you what you need to set up.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I'll look at it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are properly drawing a list of vertices, but as the error said it had no shader. Quick note about shaders: since there are no custom shaders on WP7, this means you're not applying any `Effect`; WP7 is limited to the `Effect` subclasses that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.aspx). They essentially contain built-in shaders.

In the second example you have a shader set up, but now you are not drawing from any list or buffer. `DrawUserIndexedPrimitves` takes an array of indices & vertices. It uses those to draw. `DrawPrimitives` doesn't; it relies on a vertex buffer being bound to the graphics device.

Either change that second example to `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` and pass in your arrays (`cubeVertices` and...wait, you don't have an indices array, make one) to it, or set up a `VertexBuffer` with the same information and bind it as follows:

`Controller.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vb);`

Comment: So which way would be more efficient under the hood? Or which way would be better with expectation of being able to combine several primitives from different functions to make a large mesh in order to minimize the number of calls being sent to the GPU?

Comment: In terms of batching many vertices together, you can do that with either method; simply put as many as you can in the same draw call, whether it's drawing primitives directly or buffering. Submission to the graphics card is typically going to be done either way. Buffering offers advantages by storing vertices in a more GPU-ready format, saving a bit of work of boiling all those verts down.

Comment: Alright, I tried using the first example to keep it simple and made a BasicEffect and it works. However, the line shows up as white even though I've specified the vertices to be black. Code here: http://pastebin.com/n8QnVWKJ

I want to use a buffer but from what I've seen you can only "set" the buffer and not append the buffer. Thank you.

Comment: You are using vertex coloring but not [enabling it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.vertexcolorenabled.aspx).

Comment: Thanks man. It works perfectly for now. I'll see about getting polygons and consolidating everything into a single buffer. Would you happen to know off hand how to combine a lot different buffers at load time (assuming the same texture or no texture at all)